# How to check if CSV file has a comma or a semicolon as separator?

Tags: r, csv, import, read.csv

I have to read in a lot of CSV files automatically. Some have a comma as a delimiter, then I use the command `read.csv()`.

Some have a semicolon as a delimiter, then I use `read.csv2()`.

I want to write a piece of code that recognizes if the CSV file has a comma or a semicolon as a a delimiter (before I read it) so that I don´t have to change the code every time.

My approach would be something like this:

```
try to read.csv("xyz")
if error 
read.csv2("xyz")
```

Is something like that possible? Has somebody done this before?
How can I check if there was an error without actually seeing it?

Comment: `fread` in the data.table package will automatically determine the separator and then read the file in.

Comment: Have you tried using `fread` from `data.table`? `fread` has a built-in automatic detector separator. An alternative would be to use `readLines` or something to that effect.

Comment: `fread` from the `data.table` package will auto-detect this and will read in much faster than `base` functions.

Comment: Okay thanks i am going to try that...

Comment: haha hi5 team we just blitzed this question with `fread`.

Comment: But what if I just need to know the separator for a later process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few approaches assuming that the only difference among the format of the files is whether the separator is semicolon and the decimal is a comma or the separator is a comma and the decimal is a point.

**1) fread**  As mentioned in the comments `fread` in data.table package will automatically detect the separator for common separators and then read the file in using the separator it detected.  This can also handle certain other changes in format such as automatically detecting whether the file has a header.

**2) grepl**  Look at the first line and see if it has a comma or semicolon and then re-read the file:

```
L <- readLines("myfile", n = 1)
if (grepl(";", L)) read.csv2("myfile") else read.csv("myfile")
```

**3) count.fields**  We can assume semicolon and then count the fields in the first line. If there is one field then it is comma separated and if not then it is semicolon separated.

```
L <- readLines("myfile", n = 1)
numfields <- count.fields(textConnection(L), sep = ";")
if (numfields == 1) read.csv("myfile") else read.csv2("myfile")
```

**Update**  Added (3) and made improvements to all three.

Comment: to all the others: I didnt know fread before. Seems a nice tool,  thank you too!

Comment: But what if I just need to know the separator for a later process?

Comment: See the `grep` in (2) or `numfields` in (3).

Answer (score 4):

A word of caution. read.csv2() is designed to handle commas as decimal point and semicolons as separators (default values). If by any chance, your csv files have semicolons as separators AND points as decimal point, you may get problems because of dec = "," setting. If this is the case and you indeed have separator as the ONLY difference between the files, it is better to change the "sep" option directly using read.table()

Comment: All files with semicolon as a separator have commas as decimal point! All files with comma as separator have points as decimal point, so thats the good thing about it

Comment: That's how things are designed to be. With de facto existing freedom to save a file with any combination of features, you have no guarantee that you will have any expected restrictions in a file you are given. Somebody out there could save a file with dec="." and sep=";". I have seen those in real life.