# R shiny get files seperator

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to know the file separator after loading ??

My need is to have the file seperator to use it in options like read.table.
read.table(filename, encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE, fill=TRUE,sep=XXXX)

Comment: What about https://github.com/nicholasjcooper/reader/blob/master/reader.R#L1211 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417242/how-to-check-if-csv-file-has-a-comma-or-a-semicolon-as-separator

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but it sounds like you're trying to figure out the original file separator after loading a file using `read.table`.

Unfortunately the answer is "no."

But you can write a wrapper function that (attempts to) capture this information after the fact:

```
read_table_capture_args <- function(...) {
  # capture unevaluated arguments
  outer_call <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  dots <- outer_call$...

  # pass those arguments to read.table() and save the result
  inner_call <- as.call(c(as.name("read.table"), dots))
  result <- eval(inner_call)

  # update the captured arguments with the implied default arguments
  all_args <- formals(read.table)
  implicit_argnames <- setdiff(names(all_args), names(dots))
  for (argname in implicit_argnames) {
      inner_call[[argname]] <- all_args[[argname]]
  }

  # return the result with an attribute "call" that contains all of the
  # arguments, explicit and implicit, used to produce the result
  structure(result, call = inner_call)
}
```

You can then use this to recover the `sep` argument like so:

```
# load your data as usual
my_data <- read_table_capture_args(text = "x,y,z\n1,2,3\n4,5,6", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
# get the unevaluated call that was used to load your data
my_data_call <- attr(my_data, "call")
# get the value of sep that was passed
my_data_sep <- my_data_call$sep
```