# R package that recognizes tilde delimiter automatically

Tags: r, delimiter, fread

I can get `fread` with `sep="~"` to work, but I'd rather not have to provide the `sep` parameter, but without it, it does not recognize the `~` as the file delimiter.

Is there a way to detect the separator myself first upfront using something like `readLines`, or another package that can do this out-of-the-box?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33417611/1552004)? Edit: Now I see you commented on that answer. Does this approach not work for you? [reader](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reader/) also has a `get.delim` function.

Comment: What rule do you want to use to automatically detect a delimiter? If you can define a rule, you can write code to check for it.

Comment: The readLines approach will work for me.  My rule will just be that the count of the delimiter being currently tested > ~10 (our datasets should have more than 10 columns).  It's not perfect, but it will only be used when fread cannot do it automatically