# Import several csv for a list that could have comma or semicolon - R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to import 2546 csv files to a list in R, and all of them have two header rows with different number of columns.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

I could import the csv files but some of them are delimited with semicolon instead of comma, and is affecting the rest of the code. I've seen a related post but could not find a solution for lists of csv's.
[How to check if .csv-File has a comma or a semicolon as separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417242/how-to-check-if-csv-file-has-a-comma-or-a-semicolon-as-separator)

So I've done the line of code below, but it is not working

```
myfiles <- sapply(temp, fread, simplify=FALSE)
```

Hope I am being clear on my explanation to have your help, as I am just new in R. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you tell us why the `fread` option is not working? Do you receive any error? If so, post it so we can get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: There was 50 warnings, but I went to check the files and still had some of them with just one column cause are separated by semicolon. Do you want me to check the warnings to post here?

Comment: Sure, post some of the warnings here.

Comment: I am not sure if the warnings are related to "fread"

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Stopped early on line 259. Expected 37 fields but found 36. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<2018-03-03T04:18:51+00:00,TL-1337H10DE2018,1.72,1.56,3.328,3.392,5.12,2.976,3.28,3.184,1.016,27.8,29.8,43,34,37,34,43,2030,1.019287,0,0,0,0,34,30,32,6.779522,2.557299,3.49764,0.7245829,35,35,6.42099,34,350>>

Comment: Those warnings are definitely related to `fread`. See what it says. Line 259 is supposed to have 37 fields, but it found just 36. Maybe you have a comment char or the file is corrupt and a field is missing for some reason. Try with `fill=TRUE` as it suggests.

Comment: I've trying as it suggests with fill=TRUE but is still giving me the same error, now with 48 warnings

Comment: Could you help me using other solution?

Comment: You should check the files that are causing you problems. Check whether each row of the files got the same number of fields. The warning messages are of great help to see where the problem is.

Comment: I've checked, and as it have more fields than columns I agree to delete those rows. But I am still getting the same problem than before with the semicolon delimited files